# How to handle answer and bounty for initially incomplete question?

Tags: support, accepted-answer

Can someone tell me what's the best way to handle the answer to this [question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/70950/what-icon-does-unity-use-for-an-application) considering that it wasn't accurate when I asked it?

Should I post my own answer and accept it? Should I award the bounty to @fossfreedom since he answered the first part of the question (dash icons) and not the second part (launcher item icon) which is what I actually wanted to fix and I figured out after I asked the question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you're one the right track. The best may be to:

- Award the bounty to fossfreedom for the effort (you can't award a bounty to yourself anyway so even if it doesn't answer your intentional question it's reasonable to award a good answer to one aspect of what was actually asked for).
- If there is no answer that resembles your solution write one up yourself and post it as an answer to your own question.
- If your own answer to your question is the best, then accept it.